# Save visio file as DWG or DXFin C#

Tags: c#, office-interop, visio, dxf, dwg

Am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio to create a visio file. It's working as expected. Now the new requirement is to save the file as DWG and DXF.

I saw [Page.Export Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff767110.aspx) to export the visio file to different file type.
But using export method it's not generating the DWG and DXF other than that everything is generating.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Document doc = VisioApplication.Documents.OpenEx( sFileToWrite, stick );
int iCount = doc.Pages.Count;
for( int i = 0; i < iCount - 1; i++ )
                     {
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Page page = doc.Pages.get_ItemFromID( i + 1 );
    page.Export("E:\\thejus" + i + ".dwg" ); //not working
    page.Export("E:\\thejus" + i + ".bmp" ); //working
 }
```

Please let me know if someone knows the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

everything is correct. My visio license was expired because of that the file was not creating.

Answer (score 0):

```
Visio.Document Document=App.Documents.OpenEx("D:\\Temp\\trees_top_with_shadow.dwg", Flags);
int iCount = Document.Pages.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < iCount; i++)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Page page = Document.Pages.get_ItemFromID(i);                    
    page.Export("D:\\temp\\thejus" + i + ".svg"); //working
    page.Export("D:\\temp\\thejus" + i + ".bmp"); //working
}
```

Comment: While the code is very helpful, the OP might like a little bit of an explanation.